# Integration of Karma test cases in Jenkins which is configured to run ansible script

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, karma-runner, ansible

We are stuck with a scenario where we deploy code(written in nodejs) to remote instance through ansible scripts. We now have to integrate this code in jenkins server.

Till now we ran the pure ansible script in **EXECUTE SHELL** section of job configuration.

But now ,we need to run a series of karma test cases and upon success execute this ansible script. We have tried running karma test cases inside ansible script but that means giving control to ansible and missing reporting feature which jenkins does.

What we need is a test runner plugin of jenkins that would run test cases and upon success run this ansible script and upon failure do appropriate reporting. 
Any working example would be highly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And why doesn't the good old Conditional step work for you?

```
Add build step -> Conditional (Single)
```

[image: Add build step -> Conditional (Single)]

Comment: Is there any way to execute a shell script to run upon failure too. What i need is a mail send execution to be done only upon failure with test results sent.

Comment: @NavyCody not sure if the "mail send execution" you refer to is Jenkin's mail or your own. 1) Check what "On evaluation failure" is. 2) Else you can always add mailing logic in the shell command itself e.g. `karma_test.sh || mailx -s 'some error in karma_test.sh' -a karma_test.log < mail_contents.txt`. Or create a wrapper script to call `karma_test.sh` if you wanna impl some more complex decision making, and call that from Jenkins instead.

Comment: Hi kashyap. Iam using karma-junit-reporter to a file named test-results.xml
and an html report mail to be sent to the users.